# sql statement not working on AND (... OR ... OR ...)

Tags: sql

this is probably a little thing

but i try to use this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Colors 
WHERE colorHueWarmth < 0 
AND colorV >=0.7 
AND (fk_subCategory=4 OR fk_subCategory=5 OR fk_subCategory=11)
```

And in the results i get the perfect colorHueWarmth and colorV but i also get the fk_subcategories for other values than 4, 5 or 11.

i tried changing the values but no results, is it even possible to do such a statement?

Does anyone what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `AND fk_subCategory IN(4,5,11)` although it should work as you have it...

Comment: Can you please add sample data and sample output?

Comment: Can you post an SQLFiddle with some sample data please? Your query looks fine, and I am unable to reproduce the issue. Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: What database are you using? You might want to add some round brackets to enforce the intended operator precedences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've actually got multiple options; although I'd point out that the query (in your qusetion) actually works for me (see this [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b939/5))

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Colors 
WHERE 
    colorHueWarmth < 0 
    AND colorV >=0.7 
    AND (fk_subCategory=4 OR fk_subCategory=5 OR fk_subCategory=11)
```

As stated in one of the comments I would guess that your original didn't have braces on the `fk_subCategory` clause (the third table in my previous fiddle). Brackets are immensely important when working with logic and should always be used to group items together.

The easiest solution is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Colors
WHERE 
    colorHueWarmth < 0 
    AND colorV >=0.7 
    AND (fk_subCategory IN(4,5,11));
```

You will find loads of documentation online regarding the `LIKE` clause here are a few you might find useful:

- http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/interactive_sql_tutorial/sql_in.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp (note W3Schools can't always be taken on face value and are often excluded from suggested links due to the errors/omissions they often contain)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177682.aspx

Given the size of the foreign key constraint (4,5 or 11) the `IN` clause is a reasonable option, if you have other queries using something similar with large collections this can become quite inefficient in which case you could create a temporary table which contains the ID's and `INNER JOIN` onto that. ([here is a question regarding alternatives to `LIKE`](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=alternatives%20to%20IN%20sql))